# Best Practice for Conditional v-List items using Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

I'm building an application that needs to have its v-list items conditioned based upon the role and permissions of the end user. There will be a minimum of 4 roles.

Currently I have an array in code that the list is built from.

```
   menu_items: [
  {
    icon: "keyboard_arrow_up",
    "icon-alt": "keyboard_arrow_down",
    text: "Trainees",
    type: "link",
    model: false,
    children: [
      {
        icon: "contacts",
        text: "Application",
        type: "link",
        ref: "/trainee/application/"
      },
      {
        icon: "contacts",
        text: "Business Manager",
        type: "link",
        ref: "/trainee/businessManager/"
      },
```

and I build the menu items:

```
    <template v-slot:activator>
          <v-list-tile>
            <v-list-tile-content>
              <v-list-tile-title>{{ item.text }}</v-list-tile-title>
            </v-list-tile-content>
          </v-list-tile>
        </template>
        <v-list-tile
          v-for="(child, i) in item.children"
          :key="i"
          @click.stop="child.type === 'link' ? goPage(child.ref) : child.func.apply(this)"
        >
          <v-list-tile-action v-if="child.icon">
            <v-icon>{{ child.icon }}</v-icon>
          </v-list-tile-action>
          <v-list-tile-content>
            <v-list-tile-title>{{child.text }}</v-list-tile-title>
          </v-list-tile-content>
        </v-list-tile>
      </v-list-group>
      <v-list-tile v-else :key="item.text">
        <v-list-tile-action>
          <v-icon>{{ item.icon }}</v-icon>
        </v-list-tile-action>
        <v-list-tile-content>
          <v-list-tile-title>{{ item.text }}</v-list-tile-title>
        </v-list-tile-content>
      </v-list-tile>
    </template>
```

My question is what is the standard way to build conditional lists?  Should I pull different arrays from a database that builds it based upon the user permissions?  Should I add an item to each element that is conditioned upon the role or permission? Should the pages also have there own permissions?  I've seen a couple of YouTube videos but they are mostly just user and admin.

Sorry for the questions but working with Vue has open up different ways of building items for me.  If there is a blog or article that explains the various options that would be great also.

I know that there is never an only way to do anything but coming close it a standard is all that I'm looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best method is to create a `computed property`, do your data shaping, filtering, sorting, and grouping there, and then reference the `computed property` from your template.

```html
<li v-for='item in filteredItems'>{{item}}</li>
```

```js
data: ()=>({ myDataItems: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'foo'] }),
computed: {
  filteredItems() {
    return.myDataItems.filter(it=>!it.startsWith('foo')).sort();
  }
}
```

Comment: I was gonna suggest the same solution.